# How much SP is required to increase Dragoon levels?

Tags: legend-of-dragoon

I don't think there is any way to track your progress towards the next Dragoon level, but it would be nice to have a general idea of what to expect.

What are the total amounts of SP required for each Dragoon level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197765-the-legend-of-dragoon/faqs/10293) (see "Section 9: Dragoon Level"):

```
+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+
| Name          | Lv1 |  Lv2   |  Lv3   |  Lv4    |  Lv5    |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| DART          | 100 |  1200  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| LAVITZ/ALBERT | 100 |  1000  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| SHANA/MIRANDA | 100 |  1000  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| ROSE          | 100 |  1200  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| HASCHEL       | 100 |  1000  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| MERU          | 100 |  2000  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
| KONGOL        | 100 |  2000  |  6000  |  12000  |  20000  |
+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+
```